Buoyant force application
An open bottle lies on a precise weighing scale. A fly then enters the bottle and flutters around in futile attempt to escape. Another fly, instead of using its wings to fly, uses a small helium filled balloon fitted to it by a microartist, in order to remain airborne.
Wouldn't the reading in both the case be same as there is a force on the fly balancing it's weight, So there would be a reaction to it causing the reading to be same?
